# How to improve performance of left join in AX Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, axapta

I'm trying to create a query to fetch dynamics AX salestable records with their history log records in a left join.
 If I filter on the salesid I naturally get the results in a split second, but if I leave out the salesid it takes forever even though SalesID SN16129492 is the only 'valid' record for 2017/03/08?:

```
Declare @Bedrijf NVARCHAR(3) = 'dat';
Declare @leverdatum_van DATE = convert(datetime, '2017/03/08');
Declare @leverdatum_tot DATE = convert(datetime, '2017/03/08');
Declare @bedrag decimal = 1;

SELECT     SUM(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT) AS waarde, SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, SALESTABLE.SALESID as ordernummer, CUSTTABLE.NAME as klantnaam,
MAX(SalesTable.createdBy) as ingevoerd_door, log.dader, log.veldnummer, log.huidigestatus, log.vorigestatus

FROM         SALESLINE INNER JOIN
                      SALESTABLE ON SALESLINE.SALESID = SALESTABLE.SALESID AND SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID 
                      INNER JOIN CUSTTABLE ON
SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID=CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID AND SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT=CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
LEFT JOIN 
(select dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 2) AS varbinary(8000)), 2) AS DADER,
dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 1) AS VELDNUMMER,
dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 2) AS HUIDIGESTATUS,
dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 3) AS VORIGESTATUS,  LOGRECID 
from SYSDATABASELOG
where TABLE_=366 AND DATAAREAID=@bedrijf 
) log
ON SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID=@bedrijf AND SALESTABLE.RECID=log.LOGRECID
WHERE (SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = @bedrijf) AND SALESTABLE.SALESTYPE=4 --retourorder
AND     (SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED between @leverdatum_van and @leverdatum_tot) 
--AND (Salestable.SALESID = 'SN16129492')
AND (SALESTABLE.SalesOrderStatus in (0,1,2,3,4,5)) 

GROUP BY SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, SALESTABLE.SALESID, CUSTTABLE.NAME, log.dader, log.veldnummer, log.huidigestatus, log.vorigestatus
HAVING     (SUM(ABS(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT))> @bedrag)
```

Is there a way to improve performance / redesign this query?

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: Is the left join with SYSDATABASELOG the main cause of performance degradation?

Comment: Run this query on SQL Server Management Studio and look at the Execution Plan. Where is the bottle neck (the node that takes the most percentage of time) ?.

Comment: @Etsa When I leave out the left join it takes 7 seconds, with left join it takes forever.

Comment: Execution plan added. 42% for NonClustered index seek

Comment: Other then using your exec plan results, I would work on the function CONPEEK, on the use of CAST (  .. VARBINARY(8000)), and on the "data" field

Comment: I think the part SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID=@bedrijf in the ON condition could be removed.

Comment: @etsa I need the conpeek function to get the contents of the sysdatabaselog containers 
[link]http://abraaxapta.blogspot.nl/2011/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-containers-from.html

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly include dataareaid AND partition in conditions for all tables (you can either add it as a filter, or in join conditions), *even if you just have a single partition*.

By default, AX2012 implicitly adds the dataareaid and partition fields to all indexes created in the AOT as the *first two fields*.

As we found, SQL server is notoriously bad with handling these kinds of indexes, apart from the fact that it can't just "skip" the first level if you don't provide it explicitly (partition), it is also really bad at estimating index statistics (SQL server does a histogram for the first field in the index, and assumes the rest of the fields in the index have a normal distribution).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I couldn't write code so long in a comment.
The result could be different, but it's just to help us understand if a part of your query degrade performance (GROUP BY).  I moved part of group fields outside.
Can you try this and see if it is "going forever" (using your words)?

```
 SELECT A.*
        ,log.dader
        ,log.veldnummer
        ,log.huidigestatus
        ,log.vorigestatus
    FROM (
            SELECT SUM(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT) AS waarde
                ,SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT
                ,SALESTABLE.SALESID AS ordernummer
                ,CUSTTABLE.NAME AS klantnaam
                ,MAX(SalesTable.createdBy) AS ingevoerd_door
                ,SALESTABLE.RECID    /* ADDED THIS */
            FROM SALESLINE
            INNER JOIN SALESTABLE ON SALESLINE.SALESID = SALESTABLE.SALESID AND SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID
            INNER JOIN CUSTTABLE ON SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID AND SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
            WHERE SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = @bedrijf
                AND SALESTABLE.SALESTYPE = 4 --retourorder
                AND SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED BETWEEN @leverdatum_van AND @leverdatum_tot
                --AND (Salestable.SALESID = 'SN16129492')
                AND SALESTABLE.SalesOrderStatus IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            GROUP BY SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT
                ,SALESTABLE.SALESID
                ,CUSTTABLE.NAME
                ,SALESTABLE.RECID    /* ADDED THIS */
            HAVING SUM(ABS(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT)) > @bedrag
            ) A
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 2) AS VARBINARY(8000)), 2) AS DADER
                ,dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS VARBINARY(8000)), 1) AS VELDNUMMER
                ,dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS VARBINARY(8000)), 2) AS HUIDIGESTATUS
                ,dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS VARBINARY(8000)), 3) AS VORIGESTATUS
                ,LOGRECID
                FROM SYSDATABASELOG
                WHERE TABLE_ = 366
                AND DATAAREAID = @bedrijf) log ON SALESTABLE.RECID = log.LOGRECID
```

Comment: Cancelled the query after 15 minutes, thanks for trying etsa

Comment: I think this can anyway give you some elements: if the first part of the query (as before) is fast enough, but adding the join to SYSDATABASELOG execution time is too high, it should depend by SYSDATABASELOG and/or CONPEEK...

Comment: If I keep the left join to sysdatabaselog but remove the conpeek (function) and just leave the: SELECT A.*,log.LOGRECID it takes 6 seconds. If I filter the sysdatabaselog records to only select records where one of the datefields >= SalesTable createddatetime  CONVERT(Date, CREATIONDATETIME) >= @leverdatum_van) the results take 30 seconds..

Comment: ...I think you are finding the right way and will be able to resolve it, one step after the other.   :-)   Usually use of functions and long text columns can cause performance problems (the former elaboration time, the latter IO pages access)

Answer (score 0):

By adding filters for createddatetime for bot left and right table I've decreased processing time from 'forever' to < 30 seconds for a period of one month.

Optimized Query:

```
Declare @Bedrijf NVARCHAR(3) = 'dat';
Declare @leverdatum_van DATETIME = convert(datetime, '2017/03/01');
Declare @leverdatum_tot DATETIME = convert(datetime, '2017/04/01');
Declare @bedrag decimal = 1;

SELECT     SUM(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT) AS waarde, SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, SALESTABLE.SALESID as ordernummer, CUSTTABLE.NAME as klantnaam,
MAX(SalesTable.createdBy) as ingevoerd_door, log.dader, log.veldnummer, log.huidigestatus, log.vorigestatus
FROM     SALESLINE 
INNER JOIN SALESTABLE 
ON SALESLINE.SALESID = SALESTABLE.SALESID AND SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID 
INNER JOIN CUSTTABLE 
ON SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID=CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID AND SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT=CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
LEFT JOIN  (
                           select dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 2) AS varbinary(8000)), 2) AS DADER,
                                        dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 1) AS VELDNUMMER,
                                        dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 2) AS HUIDIGESTATUS,
                                        dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 5) AS varbinary(8000)), 3) AS VORIGESTATUS,  LOGRECID 
                           from SYSDATABASELOG
                           where TABLE_=366 AND DATAAREAID=@bedrijf 
                           and createddatetime between @leverdatum_van and @leverdatum_tot
                    ) log
ON SALESTABLE.DATAAREAID=@bedrijf AND SALESTABLE.RECID=log.LOGRECID
WHERE (SALESLINE.DATAAREAID = @bedrijf) AND SALESTABLE.SALESTYPE=4 --retourorder
AND     (SALESTABLE.createddatetime between @leverdatum_van and @leverdatum_tot) 
--AND (Salestable.SALESID = 'SN16129492')
AND (SALESTABLE.SalesOrderStatus in (0,1,2,3,4,5)) 
GROUP BY SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, SALESTABLE.SALESID, CUSTTABLE.NAME, log.dader, log.veldnummer, log.huidigestatus, log.vorigestatus
HAVING     (SUM(ABS(SALESLINE.LINEAMOUNT))> @bedrag)
```

More clustered index seeks in the new execution plan:
[image: Execution plan after optimization]

Thnx for helping me out ;)